# Does inception_v3 use dilations?

Tags: tensorflow, server, gpu, inference

I'd like to ask whether the inception_v3 model uses dilations as I am planning to run my model for inference on a server but this server only has tensorflow version 1.3 installed. This version isn't compatible with said dilations so I'd like to make sure my model would work on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No inception_v3 does not use dilations and is compatible with TF 1.3 and up however Mobilenet requires TF 1.5 and up.